# Apache / PHP Unable to communicate with Tomcat JavaBridge

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, php-java-bridge

My project uses PHP JavaBridge, I have installed WAMP, JRE 6.0, and Tomcat 6.0.32
I can now access http://localhost:8080/ successfully but when I run my PHP site it gives me the following error

> `warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to localhost:8080 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )`

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that I am using Windows 7

Comment: Are you sure you deploying your php scripts in webapp directory of tomcat?

Comment: yes I am. I forgot to mention that I am using windows 7. I just have a hunch that it has to do something with the permissions / rights on windows 7

Comment: Can you http://127.0.0.1:8080/ instead of localhost:8080? See what do you get?

Comment: @Rakesh, I cant do that coz the code uses localhost:8080 everywhere, and its like really everywhere. cant make these many changes.

Comment: Is that only error that you get or there are more?

Comment: this is the one I get in my application

Comment: @Umair can you please share the piece of code that invokes the `fsocketopen` command.

Comment: @Umair: Ever heard of search & replace? It's dead easy to do a mass search and replace (and you only need to change it at 1 known location to test if it solves your problem first). So please try using 127.0.0.1:8080 and see if it helps, just to make sure you don't have a DNS problem.

Comment: @Rakesh $socket = fsockopen ( "{$this->ssl}{$this->host}", $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 20 );

Comment: @rakesh, @wimvds : You Guys Rock ! Actually StackOverflow Rocks :). I changed my host to 127.0.0.1 in the config and the error is gone, thanks. I was reluctant to do that because this is a big project which I have been assigned to, I am just studying the code, setting it up on my localhost and trying to get used to so didnt want to take any risks :)

Comment: Can you guys give some explanation as to why that error was there and why didnt it work with *localhost*

Comment: @Umair, `fsocketopen` takes the hostname and it should be a **valid domain**, in your case, in general it could be a valid domain as long as you have an entry for localhost in your hosts file (C:\Windows\System 32\drivers\etc\hosts). See if you have something similar to that.

Comment: The major problem was the host file. Windows 7 has that entry commented which maps 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment above worked as a solution and hence this answer, so that in future others get it.

> Can you 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of localhost:8080? See what do you get?

`fsocketopen` takes the hostname and it should be a valid domain, in your case, (in general) it could be a valid domain as long as you have an entry for localhost in your hosts file `(C:\Windows\System 32\drivers\etc\hosts)`. See if you have something similar to that.